# Writing on firestore document using cloud functions(using react.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

This is my cloud function code.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.dbTest = functions.https.onCall((request, response) => {
  var doc = db.collection('users').doc('TEST');
  var data = doc.set({
    name:'TEST'
  });
});
```

And this is client-side code. I'm using react.js frontend.

```
var dbTest = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('dbTest');
dbTest()
.then(res=> {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
})
.catch(err=>{
  console.log(err);
});
```

Simply, it doesn't work. There's a record in Log that function was well executed. But I can't find any new document.
I wish I could get some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to return a promise in your Cloud Function.

This should work:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.dbTest = functions.https.onCall((request, response) => {
    var doc = db.collection('users').doc('TEST');
    return doc
      .set({
        name: 'TEST'
      })
      .then(() => {
        return { result: 'document updated' };
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'Error writing document:', error);  //Adapt as you wish, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.https.HttpsError
       });

});
```

Finally, I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/